# ¿Como enviar los datos de un formulario a diferentes documentos con botones?

Tags: php, formularios, fpdf

tengo un formulario que muestra datos impresos de una consulta, pero quiero enviar esos datos a un archivo php para generar un reporte en pdf cuando el usuario presione el botón "Generar", no se si esté funcionando correctamente ya que al recuperar esos datos en el archivo php con el metodo POST no lo recupera y me manda un error de que la variable está indefinida. Este es mi código.

```
<h1>Verifica que los datos que ingresaste sean correctos, si así lo es, presiona para generar tu ficha.</h1>


 <form action="" method="post" name="Hola">


<div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      FOLIO 
    <input name="FOLIO" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $folio ?>" />    
    </label>
  </div>

   <div  class="col-4">
    <label>
      NOMBRE
      <input name="NOMBRE" type="text"  disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nom ?>" />    
      </label>
  </div>


<div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO PATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOPA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellipa ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      APELLIDO MATERNO
      <input name="APELLIDOMA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $apellima?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      FECHA DE NACIMIENTO
      <input name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      CURP
      <input name="CURP" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $curp ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      ESTADO CIVIL 
      <input name="ECIVIL" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $ecivil ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      ESTADO DE NACIMIENTO 
      <input name="CLAVE_ESTADO_NAC" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $estadonac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      MUNICIPIO DE NACIMIENTO
      <input name="CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_NAC" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $muninac ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      ESTADO DONDE VIVE ACTUALMENTE 
      <input name="CLAVE_ESTADO_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $estadovive ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


   <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      MUNICIPIO DONDE VIVE ACTUALMENTE 
      <input name="CLAVE_MUNICIPIO_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $munivive ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     LOCALIDAD
      <input name="CLAVE_LOCALIDAD_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $localidad ?>" />  
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      COLONIA 
      <input  name="COLONIA_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $colonia ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
   <label>
      CALLE 
      <input name="CALLE_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $calle ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       CÓDIGO POSTAL 
       <input name="CP_VIVE" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $cp ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      TELÉFONO DE CASA
      <input name="TEL_CASA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $telcasa ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
     CELULAR
     <input name="CELULAR" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $celular ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
      <input name="CORREO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $correo ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      PRIMERA OPCIÓN
     <input name="PRIMERA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $primera ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     SEGUNDA OPCIÓN
     <input name="SEGUNDA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $segunda ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      TERCERA OPCIÓN 
     <input name="TERCERA_OPCION" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $tercera ?>" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       TIPO SANGUÍNEO
   <input name="TIPO_SANGUINEO" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $sangre ?>" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      NACIONALIDAD
   <input name="NACIONALIDAD" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nacionalidad ?>" />       
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
       NOMBRE DE SECUNDARIA DE PROCEDENCIA
       <input name="NOMBRE_DE_SECUNDARIA_DE_PROSEDENCIA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $secu ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      CCT DE LA SECUNDARIA DE PROCEDENCIA
      <input name="CCT_DE_SECUNDARIA" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $cct ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      NOMBRE DEL PADRE O TUTOR
      <input  name="NOMBRE_DE_PADRE_O_TUTOR" type="text" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $nombre_tutor_padre ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
     OCUPACIÓN DEL PADRE O TUTOR
     <input type="text" name="OCUPACION_DEL_TUTOR" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $ocupacion_tutor_padre ?>" />
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
       NÚMERO DE CONTACTO 1
       <input name="NUMERO_1" type="number" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $numero1 ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-3">
    <label>
       NÚMERO DE CONTACTO 2
       <input name="NUMERO_2" type="number" disabled="false" value="<?php echo $numero2 ?>" />
  </div>


   <div class="col-3">

  </div>
   <div class="col-3">

  </div>



    <div class="col-3">

  </div>


   <div class="col-3">

  </div>



    <div class="col-3">

  </div>


  <div class="col-submit">
    <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="enviar1" value="Ficha" onclick=this.form.action="Prueba3/reporte.php"
        <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
            </section>
  </div>
  <div class="col-submit">
    <input type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="enviar" value="No" onclick=this.form.action="eliminar.php"
    <section id="openmodal" class="modalDialog">
    </section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

elems.forEach(function(html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html);
);
</script>

  </form>

  </div>
```

Y este es mi código en el php que genera el pdf:

```
<?php


include('plantilla.php');
   require('conexion.php');

   /*$idr= $_POST['CURP'];
   $strConsulta = "SELECT * FROM inscripciones where CURP = '$idr'";
   $alumno = mysql_query($strConsulta);
   $fila = mysql_fetch_array($alumno);*/
   $abr=$_POST['FOLIO'];
   $pdf=new PDF('P','mm','A4');

   $pdf->AddPage();

   $pdf->Ln(5);
   $pdf->SetX(50);
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'BU', 12);
   $pdf->Cell(100, 10,'PASE DE INGRESO AL EXAMEN', 0,0,'C');

   // Título
   $pdf->SetX(170);
   $pdf->Cell(23,27,'Foto',1,0,'C');

   // Salto de línea
   $pdf->Ln(20);

   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
   $pdf->SetX(10);
   $pdf->MultiCell(100,10,utf8_decode('NÚMERO DE FOLIO: '.$abr),0,'C',0);

   $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Por alguna razón no está enviando los datos o tal vez no estoy definiendo bien la variable, pero no encuentro la solución, les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme. :'v

Comment: Proba con las dobles comillas en tu archivo PHP: $abr=$_POST["FOLIO"];

Comment: @MarioL Me manda el mismo error. :'v

Comment: La sintaxis correcta es: <input type="button" onclick = "this.form.action = 'pagina.php'; this.form.submit()" />. Probá cambiando eso

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: haz verificado si el evento onclick lo sta haciendo? 1) creo que tienes un error en la sintaxis trata colocando esto onclick="this.form.action='eliminar.php'", si te fijas coloque comillas dobles y comillas simples para englovar el eliminar.php 2) trata de colocar los evento on click con dos alert diferentes a ver si lo esta haciendo onclick="alert(1)"

Comment: No sirve ese código.